# How can I fix this reference-related error without using clone() or copy()?

Tags: rust, move

Please look at the following two functions and the error message.

Is it possible to fix those two functions without using a `clone()` or `copy()` function?

Also, can you answer the questions in the comments?

```
    pub fn Vec3::transform(vector: Vec3, matrix: Matrix3x3) -> Vec3
    {
        return Vec3 
        {
            integer: vector.integer * matrix.integer,
            double: vector.double * matrix.double,
            string: vector.string + &matrix.string,//why is "&" needed here as we are not modifying matrix.string? 
        }
    }
```

```
    pub fn Rototranslation::apply_mut(&self, vector: &Vec3) -> Vec3 //why is not a "mut" needed here?
    {
        let transformed_vector = *vector - self.origin_vector;//why do we need a dereference here?
        let temp_matrix = &self.rotation_matrix; 
        let transformed_vector = Vec3::transform(transformed_vector, temp_matrix);
        return transformed_vector + self.origin_vector;
    }
```

**Output**

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:141:70
    |
141 |         let transformed_vector = Vec3::transform(transformed_vector, &mut temp_matrix);
    |                                  ---------------                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Matrix3x3`, found `&mut &Matrix3x3`
    |                                  |
    |                                  arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
note: associated function defined here
   --> src/main.rs:49:12
    |
49  |     pub fn transform(vector: Vec3, matrix: Matrix3x3) -> Vec3 // a fake operation
    |            ^^^^^^^^^               -----------------

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

---

**Full Source Code**

```
use std::ops::{Add, Sub};

struct Vec3 
{
    pub integer: i32,
    pub double: f64,
    pub string: String,
}

impl Add<Vec3> for Vec3 //overloaded binary addition operator for Vec3 
{
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 
    {
        Vec3 
        {
            integer: self.integer + other.integer,
            double: self.double + other.double,
            string: self.string + &other.string,
        }
    }
}

impl Sub<Vec3> for Vec3 //overloaded binary subtraction operator for Vec3 
{
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn sub(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 
    {
        Vec3 
        {
            integer: self.integer - other.integer,
            double: self.double - other.double,
            string: self.string.replace(&other.string, ""),
        }
    }
}

impl Vec3 
{
    pub fn new(integer: i32, double: f64, string: String) -> Vec3
    {
        return Vec3 //constructing and returning a Vec3 object 
        {
            integer,
            double,
            string,
        }
    }
    pub fn transform(vector: Vec3, matrix: Matrix3x3) -> Vec3 // a fake operation
    {
        return Vec3 
        {
            integer: vector.integer * matrix.integer,
            double: vector.double * matrix.double,
            string: vector.string + &matrix.string,
        }
    }
    pub fn print(&self)
    {
        print!("{} ", self.integer);
        print!("{} ", self.double);
        print!("{} \n", self.string);
    }
}

struct Matrix3x3 // A fake Matrix type
{
    pub integer: i32,
    pub double: f64,
    pub string: String,
}


impl Add<Matrix3x3> for Matrix3x3 //overloaded binary addition operator for Matrix3x3 
{
    type Output = Matrix3x3;
    fn add(self, other: Matrix3x3) -> Matrix3x3 
    {
        Matrix3x3 
        {
            integer: self.integer + other.integer,
            double: self.double + other.double,
            string: self.string + &other.string,
        }
    }
}

impl Sub<Matrix3x3> for Matrix3x3 //overloaded binary subtraction operator for Matrix3x3 
{
    type Output = Matrix3x3;
    fn sub(self, other: Matrix3x3) -> Matrix3x3 
    {
        return Matrix3x3 
        {
            integer: self.integer - other.integer,
            double: self.double - other.double,
            string: self.string.replace(&other.string, ""),
        }
    }
}

impl Matrix3x3 
{
    pub fn new(integer: i32, double: f64, string: String) -> Matrix3x3 
    {
        return Matrix3x3 //constructs a Matrix3x3 object and returns it
        {
            integer,
            double,
            string,
        }
    }
    pub fn print(&self)
    {
        print!("{} ", self.integer);
        print!("{} ", self.double);
        print!("{} \n", self.string);
    }
}

struct Rototranslation
{
    pub origin_vector: Vec3,
    pub rotation_matrix: Matrix3x3,
}

impl Rototranslation 
{
    pub fn new(my_vec: Vec3, mat: Matrix3x3) -> Rototranslation 
    {
        return Rototranslation
        {
            origin_vector: my_vec,
            rotation_matrix: mat,
        }
    }    
    
    // A fake operation
    pub fn apply_mut(&self, vector: &Vec3) -> Vec3 
    {
        let transformed_vector = *vector - self.origin_vector;
        let temp_matrix = &self.rotation_matrix; // "&" needed here coz we are not using copy or clone
        let transformed_vector = Vec3::transform(transformed_vector, temp_matrix);
        return transformed_vector + self.origin_vector;
    }    
    fn print(&self)
    {
        self.origin_vector.print();
        self.rotation_matrix.print();
    }
}

fn main() 
{
    let _vec: Vec3 = Vec3::new(10, 0.01, "hello".to_string());
    _vec.print();
    
    let _mat: Matrix3x3 = Matrix3x3::new(10, 0.01, "hello".to_string());
    _mat.print();

    let _rot: Rototranslation = Rototranslation::new(_vec, _mat);
    _rot.print();
    
    let mut _vec2: Vec3 = Vec3::new(10, 0.01, "hello".to_string());
    _vec2.print();
    
    let _rotated_vec = _rot.apply_mut(&_vec2);// "&" used because we are expecting _vec2's value change
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to fix those two functions without using a `clone()` or `copy()` function?

[Yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6607d34f3c1d382632bd78522f473172). The problem is not really in transform (though I'm sure in other contexts it causes issues, specifically I've no idea why it's taking the transformation matrix by value).

It's that you implement `Add` and `Sub` as moving operations, on both parameters (aka `Trait<T> for T`), so both the initial subtraction and the final addition try to consume `origin_vector`, which they can't do because it's only accessed through a borrow.

The solution is to:

1. `impl Sub<&Vec3> for &Vec3` instead of the current, such that subtraction only borrows, `replace` creates a new string anyway so there's no need to transfer ownership.
2. `impl Add<&Vec3> for Vec3` in addition to the current, such that it's possible to add an owned Vec3 with a borrowed Vec3, whch is what is needed for the tail addition.

You then also need to fix the borrowing of the corresponding expressions resp.

```
let transformed_vector = vector - &self.origin_vector;
```

and

```
return transformed_vector + &self.origin_vector;
```

> ```
> string: vector.string + &matrix.string,
> //why is "&" needed here as we are not modifying matrix.string?
> ```

Because the standard library implements [`Add<&str> for String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26str%3E-for-String). `matrix.string` is a `String`, so you need to make it into an `&str` (or close enough, which an `&String` is thanks to [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods).

Also `&` specifically does not allow mutation, you might want to read the Rust book or something? `&` is an immutable reference type.

> ```
> pub fn Rototranslation::apply_mut(&self, vector: &Vec3) -> Vec3 
> //why is not a "mut" needed here?
> ```

Because despite your naming scheme you're not mutating anywhere? `Vec3 - Vec3` creates a new `Vec3`, so does `Vec3::transform`, as well as `Vec3 + Vec3`. There's no mutation to be seen.

> ```
> let transformed_vector = *vector - self.origin_vector;
> //why do we need a dereference here?
> ```

Because you `impl Add<Vec3> for Vec3`, so your addition wants to receive two Vec3 by value, but `vector` is an `&Vec3`. So the types don't match.

Of course you then get a borrow-checking error because you can't *move* a value out of a shared reference (which is what your impl of Add demands), and `Vec3` is not `Copy`.